# Disable coverage while running nosetests

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, coverage.py

I'm new to Python. I am new to PyCharm.
I am trying to debug through my unit tests. They are done with nosetest.

Currently, when I run my tests with the vagrant debugger, it gives me the following complaint:

```
PYDEV DEBUGGER WARNING:
sys.settrace() should not be used when the debugger is being used.
This may cause the debugger to stop working correctly.
If this is needed, please check:
http://pydev.blogspot.com/2007/06/why-cant-pydev-debugger-work-with.html
to see how to restore the debug tracing back correctly.
Call Location:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\coverage\collector.py", line 248, in 
_installation_trace
    sys.settrace(None)
```

Just going off the call location, I am assuming it does some manner of coverage while running and that the PyCharm debugger does not get along with the coverage library that nosetest is running.

If I run 'nosetests --plugins', I get the following output:

```
Plugin capture
Plugin failuredetail
Plugin xunit
Plugin deprecated
Plugin skip
Plugin multiprocess
Plugin logcapture
Plugin xcoverage
Plugin coverage
Plugin attributeselector
Plugin doctest
Plugin profile
Plugin id
Plugin allmodules
Plugin collect-only
Plugin isolation
Plugin pdb
Plugin timer
```

Is there a way to turn off coverage for my test run while I debug?

Answer (score 1):

pytest-coverage does not work with Pycharm - use the --no-cov parameter in the PyCharm test runners. If you want the coverage in then use the PyCharm's coverage runner (with the --no-cov parameter) to use the coverage that comes with PyCharm.